# IllegalThreadStateException when trying to resume suspended Camel context

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, hawtio

We have an application with several camel routes and would like to be able to stop and start (or rather pause/suspend and resume) the route processing in some situations with Jolokia/hawtio. The application works as it should and we can see the context and the routes in hawtio. Stopping and starting the routes works fine, but we'd also like to suspend/resume the whole context, which doesn't work.

When all routes and the context are started and we call `camelContext.suspend();` or click 'Suspend' in hawtio, the context is shown as 'Suspended' in hawtio, same for the routes.

Now, if we try to start/resume the context in hawtio (or call `camelContext.resume();` in code) we get an IllegalThreadStateException and afterwards the context is in state 'stopped' and there seems to be no way to restart it other than restarting the whole application.

We've tried this with our actual application and couldn't find a solution.

- Java 14.0.2
- Camel 3.7.1
- Spring Boot 2.4.2
- Jolokia 1.6.2
- hawtio 2.13.3

We've also tried this with a little test application with newer dependency versions and only a simple test route, the result was the same.

- Java 17.0.1 (also tried with 11.0.6 and 14.0.2)
- Camel 3.16.0
- Spring Boot 2.6.6
- Jolokia 1.7.1
- hawtio 2.14.5

**The stacktrace:**

```
o.a.camel.support.service.BaseService    : Error while resuming service: SpringCamelContext(CamelTestContext) with spring id application

java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: null
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:793) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelMainRunController.start(CamelMainRunController.java:40) ~[camel-spring-boot-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.boot.CamelSpringBootApplicationListener$1.onCamelContextStarted(CamelSpringBootApplicationListener.java:148) ~[camel-spring-boot-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.safelyStartRouteServices(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:196) ~[camel-base-engine-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager.doStartOrResumeRoutes(InternalRouteStartupManager.java:147) ~[camel-base-engine-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext.doResume(AbstractCamelContext.java:2585) ~[camel-base-engine-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.support.service.BaseService.resume(BaseService.java:214) ~[camel-api-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.management.mbean.ManagedCamelContext.start(ManagedCamelContext.java:292) ~[camel-management-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:72) ~[na:na]
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor43.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:262) ~[na:na]
    at java.management/javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86) ~[na:na]
    at java.management/javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1172) ~[na:na]
    at java.management/javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:1016) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.camel.support.management.MixinRequiredModelMBean.invoke(MixinRequiredModelMBean.java:72) ~[camel-support-3.16.0.jar:3.16.0]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814) ~[na:na]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802) ~[na:na]
    at org.jolokia.handler.ExecHandler.doHandleRequest(ExecHandler.java:98) ~[jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.jolokia.handler.ExecHandler.doHandleRequest(ExecHandler.java:40) ~[jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.jolokia.handler.JsonRequestHandler.handleRequest(JsonRequestHandler.java:89) ~[jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.jolokia.backend.MBeanServerExecutorLocal.handleRequest(MBeanServerExecutorLocal.java:109) ~[jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.jolokia.backend.MBeanServerHandler.dispatchRequest(MBeanServerHandler.java:161) ~[jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.jolokia.backend.LocalRequestDispatcher.dispatchRequest(LocalRequestDispatcher.java:99) ~[jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.jolokia.backend.BackendManager.callRequestDispatcher(BackendManager.java:429) ~[jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.jolokia.backend.BackendManager.handleRequest(BackendManager.java:158) ~[jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.jolokia.http.HttpRequestHandler.executeRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:197) ~[jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.jolokia.http.HttpRequestHandler.handlePostRequest(HttpRequestHandler.java:131) ~[jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.jolokia.http.AgentServlet$3.handleRequest(AgentServlet.java:493) ~[jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.jolokia.http.AgentServlet.handleSecurely(AgentServlet.java:383) ~[jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.jolokia.http.AgentServlet.handle(AgentServlet.java:354) ~[jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at org.jolokia.http.AgentServlet.doPost(AgentServlet.java:317) ~[jolokia-core-1.7.1.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.60.jar:9.0.60]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

**Dependencies:**

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <jolokia-core.version>1.7.1</jolokia-core.version>
    <camel-version>3.16.0</camel-version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.16.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-file-starter</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-management</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
        <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
        <version>${jolokia-core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**The test route:**

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:src/data?noop=true")
                .routeId("ROUTE1")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "ROUTE1 entered")
                .to("file://target/test");
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest what we are doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with Java 11? According to the documentation newer versions are not [officially supported](https://camel.apache.org/manual/what-are-the-dependencies.html) yet so you might run in to issues with them.

Comment: Yes, the IllegalThreadStateException occurs with Java 11, 14 and 17.